# swiftmailer does not send emails

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I want to send emails using symfony, but the swiftmailer does not send out any emails. I even dont get error reportings or anything else. Thats my code:

```
$mail = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject('Subject')
                ->setTo('test@example.com') #this is replaced by real email of course
                ->setFrom('test@example.com')
                ->setBody('Testbody');

        $this->get('mailer')->send($mail);
```

Thats the config:

```
swiftmailer:
default_mailer: mailer
mailers:
    mailer:
        transport: "%mailer_transport%"
        host:      "%mailer_host%"
        username:  "%mailer_user%"
        password:  "%mailer_password%"
        #spool:     { type: memory }
```

I even tried to set the host to an address that does not exist, but I dont get any error from swiftmailer or symfony.

I tried to find the files for the lib, but there is no Swift_Message or newInstance anywhere in the symfony files, strange

Comment: What are the params you are using that SM config is taking? Also do you have a running mailer server?

Comment: do you want to have my mailserver credentials? :) its an external mailserver. When I change the server-host to a non working address for example, I even do not get any error by swiftmailer

Comment: if your external mailer is working fine then the code you show here looks OK. Are you sure there is not something else that is preventing your code from sending a message?

Comment: Did you try this in the `prod` or `dev` environment of your application?

Comment: dev environment, shouldnt I get an error when the host does not exist?

Comment: I would try it with Google just to be sure first:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/email/gmail.html

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Validation de votre commande')
            ->setFrom('test@example.com') 
            ->setTo('test@example.com')
            ->setBody('Testbody');
            ->setCharset('utf-8')
            ->setContentType('text/html')
            ->setBody('test');

    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

in app/config/parametres.yml :

```
mailer_transport: gmail
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
mailer_user: your mail
mailer_password: your password mail
```

in app/config/config.yml :

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

Comment: why do you assume I have a gmail account?

Comment: The best solution is to use gmail account

Comment: that comment should be minus votet. Thats very far from an solution

Answer (score 0):

I had seen someone with the same problem. For him the problem was with the spool queue. It is solved by either disabling spool explicitly:

```
spool:
      enabled:false
```

or flushing the queue in the code:

```
$this->get('mailer')->send($mail);
$spool = $this->get('mailer')->getTransport()->getSpool(); 
$spool->flushQueue($this->get('mailer')->getTransport());
```

Hope it works!

Comment: as you can see in my question, sppol is not activated, I even checked it but didnt find mails there